# PHP AJAX Post text and Show after Post

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, post

I wondered- how do I make something like Facebook or Twitter post system - When I enter text in postarea and click submit, it inserts data into database and immediately shows what I just entered?
I have this JS code

```
$(function()
{
    $(".inpPostBtn").click(function()
    {
        var textcontent = $("#postTextarea").val();
        var dataString = 'postTextarea='+ textcontent;
        if(textcontent=='')
        {
            alert("Enter some text..");
            $("textarea").focus();
        }
        else
        {
            $("#flash").show();
            $("#flash").fadeIn(400).html('<span class="load">Loading..</span>');
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "insertPost.php",
                data: dataString,
                cache: true,
                success: function(html)
                {
                    $("#show").after(html);
                    document.getElementById('postTextarea').value='';
                    $("#flash").hide();
                    $("#postTextarea").focus();
                }  
            });
        }
    return false;
    });
});
```

and this PHP code:

```
<?php
include('inc/connect.php');
session_start();

$username = $_SESSION['user_login'];

$userSql = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE username="'.$username.'"';
$userRes = mysql_query($userSql);
$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($userRes);

$postBody = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postTextarea']);
$postDate = date('Y-m-d');
$postTime = date('H:i:s');
$postAuthor = $user['firstname']." ".$user['lastname'];
$postAuthorID = $user['id'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO posts (body,author,postDate,postTime,posterID) VALUES ('".$postBody."','".$postAuthor."','".$postDate."','".$postTime."','".$postAuthorID."')";
$query = mysql_query($sql);

?>
```

And finally HTML code, where posts appears (sadly after reloading page):

```
<div class="friendPosts">
    <div class="postMain">
        <div class="friendPic">
            <img src="img/profile.jpg" class="profilePic" />
        </div>
        <div class="nameDate">
            <div class="friendName">
                <a href=""><?php echo $post['author']; ?></a> <span><b>&middot;</b> <?php echo $post['postDate']; ?> <?php echo $post['postTime']; ?></span><?php if($post['posterID'] == $user['id']) { ?><a href="" title="Delete post"><span style="float: right;" class="deletePost">X</span></a><?php } ?>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div class="friendPost">
            <?php
            $myposts = $post['body'];
            echo "<p>".$myposts."</p>";
            ?>
        </div>
        <div class="postMenu">
            <a href="">Like</a> <b>/</b> <a href="">Dislike</a> <b>&middot;</b> <a href="">Share</a> <b>&middot;</b> <a class=".toggleComment">Comment (10)</a> <b>&middot;</b> <a href="">Flag</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope you can help. Thanks.

Comment: data: {'postTextarea': textcontent},

Comment: Few comments: I recommend using .on("click", function(){.. event listeners since they can handle dynamic content. Also it makes no sense to return a false from an event listener. You should also define the character encoding in your ajax call. One more thing: It's bad habit to mix between jQuery and raw javascript (document.getEle... ).

Answer (score 1):

If you use an AJAX call to submit the form, i recommend it to look like this:

```
var input = $("#term").val(); /*your input field*/
$.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'search',
            data: {
                term: input,
            },
            success: function(response) {
                $('#divToShowStuff').append(response);
            }
        });
```

In this case i submit the form and send it to the search controller in my php framework. The data field is needed to get the input from the client side to the server side. So in my search i call:

```
$_POST['term']
```

and the on success shows what the search controller sends to his view in the div on the client side.

Hope this could help a bit.